yaws is stucked and can not receive any new HTTP connection
We used yaws server with embedded mode and the server can be started to process some requests.
HAProxy is used in front end to monitor yaws cluster nodes and receive/dispatch new HTTP webpage/websocket connections.
yaws node will be stucked suddenly and can not receive any new HTTP connection.
We tried to use observer_cli to check the erlang VM node and found the stucked node:

yaws_server process stucked a Messsage:  [{inet_async, #Port<0.14205>, 4242, {ok, #Port<0.17083>}}]   the Message is not processed and flushed
the function call is  yaws_server:acceptor0/2  , Function: prim_inet:accept0/2

We had tested yaws version 2.0.6, 2.0.9 and tried to change the erlang version 20, 25.
The problem always happened randomly.



